# Using SmartGWT-extensions EventBus

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT, and I'd like to leverage the SmartGWT-extensions event bus:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4010

http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-extensions/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/smartgwt/extensions/client/eventbus/EventBus.java?r=66

There are entries in the SmartGWT forum about its use, however, there are appear to be no real-world or concrete examples of using it.

Does anyone have a sample code snippet or any other material that could demonstrate its use?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I only used Gwt SimpleEventBus in my Smartgwt app and is very happy with it, I put some details on my blog ([here](http://albuweb.blogspot.com/2011/08/eventbus-code.html) and [there](http://albuweb.blogspot.com/2011/08/eventbus_05.html)) , re - reading it now tell me it's not really clear so look at it and we can talk about it after.
Regards

Alain

Comment: I actually ended up using the GWT EventBus as well.  It's a better solution, because it allows for type safety, so you can catch mistakes at compile time.  Works great, and definitely allows for de-coupling code.